# Support Renderscript crashing on API 23

Tags: android, renderscript

I get the following exception when I run renderscript on Marshmallow

```
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI NewGlobalRef called with pending     exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no static or non-static method "Landroid/support/v8/renderscript/RenderScript;.nDeviceDestroy(J)V"
```

gradle config

```
    renderscriptTargetApi 22
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
```

I am using renderscript for blur transformation, works fine on api level less than 23

Comment: What your version of android renderscript support library?

Comment: I am using the support v8 

android.support.v8.renderscript.ScriptIntrinsicBlur;

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this issue?

Comment: I downgraded to  renderscriptTargetApi 20 and didnt have issues since, havent tried upgrading to the latest one